# analytical function -- Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

put  $ D = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} : ‎\mid\lambda‎‎\mid <‎ ‎1\}$  and
$‎A( D ) = \{ f ‎\in C (‎\overline{D}‎)   : f ‎\vert‎_{D} ‎\,\text{ ‎is analytic}\} $‎.

> show that $A(D)$ is a closed sub algebra of  $C (‎\overline{D}‎)$ , then it is a  with identity?

Comment: Notice that by definition $A(D)\subset C(\overline{D})$. So you only need to show that products, sums and linear combinations of elements in $A(D)$ are again in $A(D)$.

Comment: how to show analytic property?

Comment: You have to show that products of analytic function are again analytic, this should be straightforward.